# Calculating average by adding all the month's average percentage average

Tags: javascript, html, css

Performing calculation in JavaScript but parts of the calculation are not working.
I tried all the possible ways by looking at examples form online to calculate or add all the Response Percent from the months Jan to Dec to get its
average and display the average in the total average under total response but my code below is not working properly

Also I want to save the selected options from the user when open the web page again the selected options still there.

```js
const $select_rows = $('.select_row');
const $percent_row = $('.percent_row');

function update_column(col_index) {
  const child_index = col_index + 2; // 1 indexed plus 1 for row heading
  const $selects = $select_rows.find('td:nth-child(' + child_index + ') select');

  if ($selects.length) {
    let yes_count = 0;
    $selects.each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        yes_count++;
      }
    });

    $percent_row.find('td:nth-child(' + child_index + ') .cnt-percent-y').text((yes_count * 100 / $selects.length).toFixed(2));
  }
}

function setup() {
  $select_rows.each(function() {
    $(this).find('select').each(function(index) {
      const col_index = index;

      $(this).change(function() {
        update_column(col_index);
      });

      update_column(col_index);
    });
  });
}

setup();

function average(perResponse) {

  var total = 0;
  var perRseponse;
  for (var i = 0; i < perResponse.length; i++) {
    total += perResponse[i];
  }
  var avg = total / source.length;
  alert(avg)
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = avg;
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<title>Finding Average</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <p style="font-family:georgia,garamond,serif;font-size:16px;font-style:italic;">
    Finding Average & Calculation of Total Percentage
  </p>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Bought Office Supplies</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Saving's Over $25,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $10,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $20,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="Percentage"><span class="cnt-percent-y">0</span>% <br></div>
        </td> //Here goes the average total from calculation from the average from Jan to Dec
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Comment: Question is not really clear, and should be broken into multiple questions, it looks like. Perhaps this will get you started: `let rowCount = $('tbody>tr').length*12, yeses = 0; $('tbody>tr>td>select').each(function(i, e){ const t = $(e); if(t.val() === 'Yes')yeses++; }); let percent = yeses/rowCount*100;`?

Comment: I tried getting the average percentage of  of all month from Jan to dec by adding all the total response percent and divided it by 12 n display in the very last column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of, there's no need for jQuery since the advent of `.querySelector` and `.querySelectorAll`, I've created the following example for you to study. The nested looping design is complex, if you haven't done anything like this before. In time you'll understand.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
S = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  let w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
hC = (node, className)=>{
  return node.classList.contains(className);
}
aC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.add(...classNames);
  return aC;
}
rC = (node, ...classNames)=>{
  node.classList.remove(...classNames);
  return rC;
}
tC = (node, className)=>{
  node.classList.toggle(className);
  return tC;
}
// small Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load Event *(except // end load line)*
const trs = Q('tbody>tr'), trsL = trs.length, prs = Q('tfoot>tr>td+td'), prsM = prs.length-1, ya = [];
function showAverages(){
  for(let i=0,endTd; i<trsL; i++){
    endTd = S('td:last-child', trs[i]);
    endTd.textContent = (ya[i].reduce((r, v)=>r+v)/12*100).toFixed(2);
  }
  let total = 0;
  for(let p=0,c,t,l=ya.length; p<prsM; p++){
    c = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<l; i++){
      c += ya[i][p];
    }
    t = (c/l*100).toFixed(2); prs[p].textContent = t; total += (+t);
  }
  prs[prsM].textContent = (total/prsM).toFixed(2);
}
for(let i=0,r,sels,y; i<trsL; i++){
  r = trs[i]; sels = Q('select', r); ya.push([]);
  for(let n=0,s,q=sels.length; n<q; n++){
    s = sels[n]; s.value = 'Yes';
    y = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
    ya[i].push(y);
    s.oninput = ()=>{
      ya[i][n] = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
      showAverages();
    }
  }
}
showAverages();
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{ /* set font-size separate to avoid white space issues */
  box-sizing:border-box; font-size:0; padding:0; margin:0;
}
p{
  font:italic 16px Georgia, Garamond, serif;
}
table{
  width:100%; table-layout:fixed; border-collapse:collapse;
}
thead *,tfoot *{
  font:bold 16px Arial, san-serif;
}
tbody *{
  font:15px Arial, sans-serif;
}
td,th{
  width:90px; border:1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; padding:8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){
  background:#ddd;
}
tbody>tr>td:last-child:after,tfoot>tr>td:not(:first-child):after{
  content:'%'; font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Finding Average</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <p>
    Finding Average &amp; Calculation of Total Percentage
  </p>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Bought Office Supplies</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Saving's Over $25,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $10,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $20,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<html>
</body>
```

Comment: With the help from you  im progressing more on learning JavaScript, JQuery, HTML and CSS. Im trying to show average percentage in the row called Response Percent till Peter only and the total average percentage i want to show beside the heading. But it is also showing an extra set of percentage of each row which i dont want. I tried to to fix using many methods i know and with the help of other Stackoverflow question and online but nothing helped.

Comment: Response Percent till Peter? What does that mean? You don't want the monthly percents at the bottom? You don't want the yearly percents in each row? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for confusion. ignore the part "Response Percent till Peter?"  Yes i want the monthly percents at the bottom. i dont want yearly percents in each row. Also is it possible to show the total average percentage beside the heading instead of showing it in the total average

Comment: It's very easy to make those changes yourself. Ask a new question, if necessary.

Comment: This site was not created for you to get people to do your work for you. It's for you to learn how to program by yourself. The example I created was for you to study. If you can't understand something, look it up. If you still don't understand, ask another question.

Comment: please see this site i did corrections -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001096/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-data-and-display-total-average-per

Comment: Really... Simply removing `for(let i=0,endTd; i<trsL; i++){
    endTd = S('td:last-child', trs[i]);
    endTd.textContent = (ya[i].reduce((r, v)=>r+v)/12*100).toFixed(2);
  }` from within `ShowAverages` would get rid of the ends.

Comment: thats what i did yesterday and i also tried to show the average in heading but didnt work. See the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001096/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-data-and-display-total-average-per