# How to reload current page without losing any data and Display Total Average Percentage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im trying to display/show the Total Average in the heading (beside it) and not in the dataset table. I tried different methods but it wont show. (The last method I tried to work with is what in including in the codes.

Also im trying to save the user input or selection data on webpage even after the page reloads or refresh. It should make changes when user made changes to it

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, S, Q, hC, aC, rC, tC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', () => {
  doc = document;
  htm = doc.documentElement;
  bod = doc.body;
  nav = navigator;
  M = tag => doc.createElement(tag);
  I = id => doc.getElementById(id);
  mobile = /Mobi/i.test(nav.userAgent);
  S = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelector(selector);
  }
  Q = (selector, within) => {
    let w = within || doc;
    return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
  hC = (node, className) => {
    return node.classList.contains(className);
  }
  aC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.add(...classNames);
    return aC;
  }
  rC = (node, ...classNames) => {
    node.classList.remove(...classNames);
    return rC;
  }
  tC = (node, className) => {
    node.classList.toggle(className);
    return tC;
  }
  // small Library above - magic below can be put on another page using a load Event *(except // end load line)*
  const trs = Q('tbody>tr'),
    trsL = trs.length,
    prs = Q('tfoot>tr>td+td'),
    prsM = prs.length - 1,
    ya = [];

  function showAverages() {

    let total = 0;
    for (let p = 0, c, t, l = ya.length; p < prsM; p++) {
      c = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        c += ya[i][p];
      }
      t = (c / l * 100).toFixed(2);
      prs[p].textContent = t;
      total += (+t);
    }
    prs[prsM].textContent = (total / prsM).toFixed(2);
    var element = document.getElementById(prs[prsM]);
  }

  for (let i = 0, r, sels, y; i < trsL; i++) {
    r = trs[i];
    sels = Q('select', r);
    ya.push([]);
    for (let n = 0, s, q = sels.length; n < q; n++) {
      s = sels[n];
      s.value = 'Yes';
      y = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
      ya[i].push(y);
      s.oninput = () => {
        ya[i][n] = s.value === 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
        showAverages();
      }
    }
  }

  showAverages();
}); // end load
//]]>


//Refresh Section but should not change anything even after refresh or reload

//window.onload = function() {
 // var a = sessionStorage.getItem('select_row');
 // if (a !== null) {
  //  //alert(a);
 //   document.getElementById("select_row").value = a;
  //}
//}

//window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 // sessionStorage.setItem("select_row", $('#select_row').val());
//}
```

```css
/* css/external.css */

* {
  /* set font-size separate to avoid white space issues */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font: italic 16px Georgia, Garamond, serif;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead *,
tfoot * {
  font: bold 16px Arial, san-serif;
}

tbody * {
  font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
}

td,
th {
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

tfoot>tr>td:not(:first-child):after {
  content: '%';
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
  <title>Finding Average</title>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Finding and Display Average: <span id="element"></span></p>
  <!--the total average goes here-->
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Jan</th>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <th>May</th>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <th>Jul</th>
        <th>Aug</th>
        <th>Sept</th>
        <th>Oct</th>
        <th>Nov</th>
        <th>Dec</th>
        <th>Total Average</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr class="percent_row">
        <td>Response Percent</td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Bought Office Supplies</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Saving's Over $25,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Savings</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $10,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="select_row">
        <td>Over Budget $20,000</td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: localstorage or server

Comment: You are not setting the value of the inputs. a tr element does not have a value

Comment: local storage and also i was  planning to see if i could do it on server side but the xampp server does not do anything while i tried from you

Comment: But when user selects an option wont that count as input

Comment: A TR is an table Row.... it has nothing to do with the select values. You need to read each selects value. You can look into jQuery's serialize and see if it helps. Some way you need to store all the states and reapply it.

Comment: how would i do that or implement that

Comment: for that save data i will do later because its difficult for me ut how will i do this Im trying to display/show the Total Average in the heading (beside it) and not in the dataset table. I tried different methods but it wont show. (The last method I tried to work with is what in including in the codes.